# Windows 7 unbootable HDD - is office installed?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have an old HDD with Windows 7. I cannot boot from it because its original mini-PC is not working. I can read all of the files on the drive. I would like to know if office is installed and, if it is installed, the version number. A Linux solution would be preferable.

Comment: If you can duplicate the disk to another one so as not to lose anything, you may well be able to boot the duplicate on other hardware of the same era, if it is desirable to get more information simply from the old HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through the "Program Files" (and possibly "Program Files (x86)") directories to see if there is "Microsoft Office" directory. If so, there should be a subdirectory with a name like "Office16", where 16 is the version number [(list of version numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Office)).